# Relation between RHEL_RELEASE_VERSION-macro and /etc/redhat-release

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, centos, rhel

There is a special macro `RHEL_RELEASE_CODE` that helps in preprocessing when building modules e.g. for centos kernel.

Whether the value of that macro should match the info in `/etc/redhat-release` or `lsb_release`? In other words if I see e.g. *`CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)`* inside `/etc/redhat-release`, does it mean that when I build some module, `RHEL_RELEASE_CODE` will be equal to `RHEL_RELEASE_VERSION(7,3)`?